# Paypal IPN not calling my script

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a small website where I use paypal for reccuring subscriptions.
I did the PHP code myself using what I found on blogs as the official documentation is IMO not clear at all.

Since the 6th December, it looks like paypal doesn't want to call my php script anymore (I specify the url in the notify_url of my form).
I didn't change anything in my code or on the server so does anyone got an idea why it stopped working ? 
I know this is not a php code issue because I can see in apache's logs the script is not called (and I added some debug lines that write in a file to be sure).

Here is a copy of my form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" type="hidden">
<input name="business" value="paypal@*****.com" type="hidden">
<input name="item_name" id="item_name" value="************" type="hidden">
<input name="a3" id="a3" value="6.99" type="hidden">
<input name="p3" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="t3" value="M" type="hidden">
<input name="src" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="sra" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="no_shipping" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="custom" id="custom" value="11" type="hidden">
<input name="return" value="http://*****.com/account" type="hidden">
<input name="cancel_return" value="http://*****.com/account" type="hidden">
<input name="notify_url" value="http://paypal.*****.com/paypal.php" type="hidden">
<input name="no_note" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="currency_code" value="EUR" type="hidden">
<input name="lc" value="US" type="hidden">
<input src="images/x-click-but20.gif" name="submit" alt="Subscribe with Paypal Now !" border="0" type="image">
</form>
```

I've put this at the begining of my paypal.php file to be sure to see if anything happens:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/paypaldetail',date('d-m-Y H:i:s').':[debug] '.print_r($_POST,true)."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Of course when I call the url in my browser I get an empty result but still something ..

```
26-12-2011 19:29:16:[debug] Array
(
)
```

Thanks for your ideas ;)

Comment: Did it work fine before the 6th December?

Comment: Yes it did, subscriptions and even payments after the 1st month.

Comment: i would look at the Apache access log that will tell if and when the page is visited, and that will tell you if its the script or if its really not being hit by papal

Comment: Maybe contact PayPal and ask what would stop it working after a period of time. Have they changed their API?

Comment: Have a look at Profile > My selling tools > IPN (Instant Payment Notification). Most likely it automatically got disabled after your script returned a set of negative HTTP status codes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. Try this: Login to paypal, -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> update (Block Payments) -> Block accidental payments click 'no'.

Then test it again to see if the IPN will execute your script. You may want to change it back later so that is does block accidental payments.